# Get IMEI number on rooted device using adb on Android 14

Tags: android, shell, adb

Is there any adb command that I could use to get a device's IMEI/MEID?

Also is there a way to get IMEI2 as well.
I am trying to do service call to iphonesubinfo, but i don't know the transaction number in Android 14.

So far i have tried iphonesubinfo 1 and 16 but nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following command to get IMEI on Android 14

```
adb shell -n service call iphonesubinfo 1 s16 com.android.shell | cut -c 52-66 | tr -d '.[:space:]'
```

Comment: Depending on how you run this, you might need to alter the `cut -c 52-66` (make range larger), and also watch out for stray single quotes `'` which you can do by alterning `tr` to `tr -d ".[:space:]'"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward solution  but I found an alternative

Created a system app to get the IMEI from the telephony manager and printed the log.
As `getimei()` is only called if `READ_PRIVILIGED_PHONE_STATE` permission is granted and this permission is only granted to the system app.

As my device is rooted so i installed the app as a system app sent a broadcast from ADB and got the IMEI by extracting the log from logcat